# Replacing one fragment with another via ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, fragment-tab-host

I want to replace the fragment that has list view with another fragment when an item on the said list view is clicked.

Here is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private FragmentTabHost hostTab;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    hostTab = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    //hostTab = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    hostTab.setup(this,getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);

    hostTab.addTab(
            hostTab.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab 1",
                    getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.star_on)),
            FragmentTab.class, null);
    hostTab.addTab(
            hostTab.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Tab 2",
                    getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.star_on)),
            FragmentTab1.class, null);
    hostTab.addTab(
            hostTab.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Tab 3",
                    getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.star_on)),
            FragmentTab2.class, null);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Here is my activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/replace"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost 

    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
   </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

And here is the code for "Tab 1".don't mind "Tab 2" and "Tab 3". The two only shows some text view

```
public class FragmentTab extends ListFragment implements OnItemClickListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    String[] values = new String[] { "Fragment1", "Fragment2", "Fragment3"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    // Create new fragment and transaction
    Fragment newFragment = new FragmentInListView();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    //transaction.show(newFragment);
    // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
    // and add the transaction to the back stack
    transaction.replace(R.id.replace, newFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.setTransitionStyle(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    // Commit the transaction
    transaction.commit();

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}   

 }
```

and here is the layout xml for "Tab 1"

```
 <LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/lv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</ListView>
```

And here is the class that will appear when an item in the list view is clicked

```
public class FragmentInListView extends Fragment {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout1,
            container, false);
        TextView tv= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
        tv.setText("Fragment in List View"); 
        return view;

}

 }
```

Please help and please feel free to ask for codes to be uploaded.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see a problem your ListView for list fragment has android:id="@+id/lv" but for list fragment it is necessary to have android:id="@android:id/list"

Comment: No it's not nessesery. If you want to use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` you don't have to define list in XML file

Answer (score 1):

You should create method for example 'ItemSelected' in Activity. Then send id of selected element from FragmentList to Activity and in Activity replace fragment. [Here is best example](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html) I can recomend you to download sample to see how fragments work

Comment: Hi sir.Thanks for the reply.Could you edit my code and post it here?I;m new to android programming.Sorry.

Comment: No, I can't do work for you. But you can download example from webiste, link in my answer and try to customise it.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by replacing:

`transaction.replace(R.id.replace,newFragment);`

with

`transaction.replace(R.id.tabcontent,newFragment);`